# Laravel: 2 DB Queries in Controller while 1 value depens on first query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables, products and subproducts.
I also have a view where I show informations about the product (View data dynamically generated from the db). On this view, all subproducts should be displayed. How can I do this? Because I loop through the first query in the view, not in the controller.

Controller:

```
public function showSpecificProduct($name)
    {
        $name = strtolower($name);
        $product = \DB::select('select * from products where name = ? LIMIT 1', [$name]);

        $subProducts = \DB::select('select * from subproducts where mainproduct = ?', [/* id from $product belongs here */]);

        return view('products.single', ['products' => $product, 'subproducts' => $subProducts]);
    }
```

View:

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                        <h3 class="box-title">{{ $product->name }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <img src="{{ $product->img }}" alt="{{ $product->name }}" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box -->
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

Also, is there a better method for doing the first query in laravel? Because I am using a foreach-loop while only having 1 row.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

**Controller**

```
public function showSpecificProduct($name)
    {
        $product = Product::with('subproducts')->where('name', $name)->first();

        return view('products.single')->with('products',$product);
    }
```

**View**

```
{{ $product->name }} // shows the name of the mainproduct no need for a foreach
```

to show the subproducts you have to do a foreach loop (if they are many )

```
@foreach (($product->subproducts as $subproduct)
{{ $subproduct->name}}
@endforeach
```

To be able to do this you have to set relations in your models and migrations first

**LIKE THIS**

**1-Migrations**

**Products migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
}
```

**SubProducts migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subproducts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('subproducts');
            $table->text('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
}
```

Refresh you migration if you dont have the right foreign key setup then

**2-Models**

add this to your **Product model**

**EDIT**

```
public function subproducts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subproduct', 'product_id'); // you can this
}
```

**Subproduct model**

```
public function product() { // i made a mistake here
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

Now feel free to use the Eloquent ORM.

Comment: Wow, great answer thank you. I completely forgot about models... I I already have the migrations is a simple `php artisan make:model` enough or do I need to do anything else afterwards in order to be able to use the Product class `Product::` Could you elaborate a bit if possible what hasMany() was again? Thank you.

Comment: of course, allright , a Product will have many subproducts right? so you have to tell eloquent that that model has many subproducts, so when you use the query i showed you in controller eloquent will figure out how to get you the related subproducts for the mainproduct(and vice versa) and yes you only need to create the models if you dont have'em already (and at the top of the controller dont forget to add `use App\Product;`

Comment: quick question. under "2-Models" you have 2x a function called subproducts(). are the names right? also i got an error after doing this. `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subproducts.products_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `subproducts` where `subproducts`.`products_id` in (2))` Looked for it approx. 30 min. there is an s after product from product_id. why? my field in the db is called product_id, and your coee from the subproducts up() also doesnt have an s...

Comment: Check my edit, i made a simple mistake , in your subproduct model change the name of the function to product and in the product model you can specify the  foreign key name as a second parameter

Comment: The inverse of `hasMany` is `belongsTo`

Comment: yea you are right, suggest an edit and i will aprove it

Answer (score 0):

You better to use  **[Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries)** for your database queries.

In the method you used, Laravel returns a JSON object. Its hard to use for another query (I was stuck here for a week).

```
$product = DB::table('products')->where('name','=','$name')->pluck('id');
```

This returns all the IDs as an array.So you can use this for the second query inside a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thank you. However there is always just 1 row returned in the first quere. Isn't there a better method? by using $product[0] for the second row with your example it is not working.

Comment: why don't you use join operations to get the answer?